# How to enable Mobile view for site in Mediawiki?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mediawiki, wikipedia

I believe I have followed everything from: Extension:MobileFrontend

I am wondering if its my export that I did from wikipedia that is messing with my mobile view.

http://www.gwart.co.uk/

I have version 1.33.0 installed with the following in my localSettings.php

```
wfLoadExtension( 'MobileFrontend' );

$wgMFAutodetectMobileView = true;

wfLoadSkin( 'Vector' );

$wgMFDefaultSkinClass = 'SkinVector'; // use Vector skin
```

I can now see a button at the bottom of the page which says `Mobile` Though clicking this, does redirect the page. I would expect this view to automatically change depending on screen size.

Regardless if I do click this and change view, nothing really changes in terms of viewing, it is still unfriendly for mobile users.

Have I missed a step in setting up the mobile view correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Vector as a mobile skin, you need to add the following to your LocalSettings.php file:

```
$wgVectorResponsive = true;
```

Please note that you need to be on MediaWiki 1.26 or later and that Vector "responsive mode" is not actively maintained. I recommend you install and configure MinervaNeue (default mobile skin for Wikipedia and other Wikimedia projects):

```
wfLoadSkin( 'MinervaNeue' );
$wgMFDefaultSkinClass = 'SkinMinerva';
```

Comment: Amazing thank you bud. So I will need to remove the `VectorResponsive` and switch to `minervaNeue` basically? Then it will just be responsive by default? no exporting anything from wikipedia?

Comment: Nope, just install MinervaNeue, enable it in your LocalSettings.php and you're good to go. :)

Comment: Humm interesting, I have this running on my site now and its still not mobile friendly without clicking the `mobile` button at the bottom, but even then lol its still rubbish

Comment: Pivot skin as a mobile first skin similar to Vector. WPTouch skin is designed for extremely small screens , with different layouts for different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and enable extension Mobile Front-end 
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileFrontend

It will automatically detect the mobile devices and switch the view to a mobile view.
So now you can use skin of your choice for the desktop and laptops and for mobile devices, MobileFrontEnd will automatically kick-in
Hope this helps